# In google sheets, how do I copy (Not Move) entire row to another sheet based on a word (Not single value) in a cell

Tags: google-sheets, row, copying

I would like to copy (Not move) the entire row to another sheet when there is a specific word in a cell.
I have a sheet named "List" with 7 columns, in the the 7th column I put notes for each row. Every time I write the word "Lead" in that column, I would like that entire row to be copied to another sheet named "Opportunity". Please note that the word "Lead" will be followed by other words in that cell, example: "Lead, wants tree removed and landscaping service". So its not a single value.

Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom function for this.
Steps:

- Tools-> Script editor.
  For example write:

  `function myFunction(input) {
      return input; 
  }`
- Go to Resources -> Triggers of current project -> Add trigger
- Choose your function name (myFunction), from table, changes then save
- In Google sheet cell write for example

> =myFunction(A1)

and change A1 cell. You will get changes.
Code of working function that copy cells value if they have word "Lead" :

```
function myFunction(input) {
  var array = [''];
  if(typeof input != 'object') {
    return array;
 } else {
    for (var name in input) {
        for (var name2 in input[name]) {
          if(input[name][name2].toString().indexOf('Lead') != -1) {
            array.push(input[name]);
         }
       }
    }
  }
  if(array.length > 1) {
    array.splice(0, 1);
  }
  return array;
}
```

Usage. In second sheet (Opportunity) past in any cell:

> =myFunction('List'!A1:G50)

Here is [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ea5urrAWXc_ppeqDBVtVzsOspP7zs1Kv8Lhcc43Wiqs/edit#gid=0) with working formula.

Comment: Thanks Dima, but I have no clue on writing functions for word searching and placing data to another sheet :/.

Comment: Thanks Dima, but unfortunately I cant get it to work. I added the trigger (myFunction, From spreadsheet, On change) I then added your script. Then,on the Opportunity sheet, I pasted the the myFunction('List'!A1:G50).

Comment: John, is there some errors showing or just empty? Did you try to change something in "List" sheet? Each formula should starts with "=" symbol, is that so to you?

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible with QUERY(). Assuming the source sheet is 'Sheet1', in sheet 'Opportunity' enter in A1:

```
=QUERY('Sheet1!A1:G', "where G contains 'Lead'", 1)
```

Change sheet name and ranges to suit.